# DE's - exact equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

im having a bit of trouble solving the following exact equation.

I have attempted it many times but cant get all the way through it on my own. To begin with when checking if it is an exact equation, I am taking the partial derivative on each equation and seeing if they equal. Although what i get is very close it is not the same, im just using the chain rule, but they do not equal.

If i just assume that it is an exact equation and continue as normal the $\frac {2y}{x^2-y^2}$ just goes back and forth after integrating and the differentiating. Im not sure what im doing wrong. Any help in solving this would be much appreciated.

$(y - \frac{2y}{x^2-y^2})dx+(x+\frac{2x}{x^2-y^2})dy = 0$

Comment: For one your equation is exact, you only need the quotient rule to check. When you check exactness you treat x and y as independent variables.

Answer (score 1):

Checking if an equation of the form

$$P(x,y)dx + Q(x,y)dy = 0$$

is exact is not really difficult, we simply have to calculate $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$ and check whether they are the same.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(y - \frac{2y}{x^2-y^2}\right) = 1 - \frac{2(x^2-y^2)+4y^2}{(x^2-y^2)^2}=1-2\frac{x^2+y^2}{(x^2-y^2)^2}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x+\frac{2x}{x^2-y^2}\right)=1+\frac{2(x^2-y^2)-4x^2}{(x^2-y^2)^2}=1-2\frac{x^2+y^2}{(x^2-y^2)^2}$$

Since the two derivatives indeed match, your equation is exact.

This means there exists a function $\Psi(x,y)$ such that its differential is given by your equation and is thus identically zero:

$$d\Psi(x,y) = \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial y}dy = \left(y - \frac{2y}{x^2-y^2}\right)dx + \left(x+\frac{2x}{x^2-y^2}\right)dy = 0 \tag1$$

Since its differential is identically $0$, we know that $\Psi(x,y) = A$ for some constant $A$ for any $(x,y)$.

Using $(1)$, we can calculate $\Psi(x,y)$.

\begin{align}
\Psi(x,y) &= \int\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x}dx\\
&= \int\left(y - \frac{2y}{x^2-y^2}\right)dx\\
&= xy + 2\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) + F(y)
\end{align}

Here, the constant of integration is replaced with a function of $y$ because the integration was with respect to $x$.

To determine $F(y)$, note that the following must hold because of $(1)$:

$$\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial y} = x + \frac{2x}{x^2-y^2} + \frac{dF}{dy} \overset{(1)}{=} x + \frac{2x}{x^2-y^2}$$

Therefore

$$\frac{dF}{dy} = 0 \implies F = B$$

for some arbitrary constant $B$.

Since we have already established that $\Psi(x,y) = A$, we can simply combine the two arbitrary constants into one constant $C:=A-B$ and thus obtain

> $$xy + 2\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) = C$$

as an implicit relation between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Is there any way to use the inverse hyperbolic tangent function without having to resort to the text-environment in MathJax?